# Dynamic URL change in jQuery Rails Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm adding an image gallery to a rails app using jQuery. I have a main image and thumbnails underneath. When a user hovers over a thumbnail, the main image is replaced with the thumbnail. And when a user hovers over the main image, it zooms to a url that points to the original image size.

**Problem:** The main image url is always the first image url. So the main image changes with thumbnail hover but the zoom always points to the same url. How do I change the main image url dynamically to be the url of the img being shown in the container?

Here is my html and jquery...note that .tnail are the thumbnail classes, #mainImage is the main image id and "thumbnail" is a bootstrap class which is the mainImage container which I call to zoom.

```
  <div class="thumbnail">
        <%= link_to image_tag(@listing.image.url, id: "mainImage", class: "zoom"),     @listing.image.url %>
 </div> 

         <%= link_to image_tag(@listing.image.url, size: "90x90"), @listing.image.url, class: "tnail" %>
         <%= link_to image_tag(@listing.image2.url, size: "90x90"), @listing.image2.url, class: "tnail" %>
         <%= link_to image_tag(@listing.image3.url, size: "90x90"), @listing.image3.url, class: "tnail" %>
         <%= link_to image_tag(@listing.image4.url, size: "90x90"), @listing.image4.url, class: "tnail" %>


            <script>
                $(".tnail img").hover(function(){
                var src = $(this).attr("src");
                $("#mainImage").attr("src",src);
                  });

                   $(".thumbnail").zoom(); /* not to confuse but "thumbnail" is a bootstrap class 
                  and is the container for the main image. Zoom is based on Jack Moore's jQuery 
                  Zoom plugin.*/

            </script>
```

From what I've seen from other questions, it seems I need a url: parameter in the zoom function. How do I call the url based on my html. I call images in rails with a link_to with image calls like `@listing.image.url`,`@listing.image2.url`, etc.

Comment: you may show some code?

Comment: Just added the erb.html.